# Variable assigned to the property of a global object not updating

Tags: javascript, reference

I'm running into an issue where a variable assigned to the property of a global object does not get updated. I know this is some kind of javascript pass by reference issue that i'm not understanding, despite having looked through some other similar SO questions. Here's the some code I wrote to test this scenario:

```
function formState (type) {
    this.current_form = { primary:null};

    this.set_primary = function(form) {
        this.current_form.primary = form;
        return this.current_form.primary;
    };

}

var schedule = function(someState) {
    someState.set_primary({"updated":"updated"});
};


var state = new formState();
var newState = state.set_primary({"new":"new"});
console.log("newState = ", newState);
schedule(state);
console.log("newState = ", newState);
```

A `console.log` at the end shows that  `newState =  { new: 'new' }`. Why is this? If `newState`is referencing a block of memory, shouldn't I be able to update that memory from anywhere and have the changes be reflected in `newState`? I'm missing something fundamental here, any help would be appreciated.

Here's the corresponding [repl](http://repl.it/Tjx/3).

Comment: Hmm ok, what you guys are saying below makes sense. But is there any way to point `newState` to the memory location of `this.current_form.primary` property instead of referring to it through the `current_form` as @ricovox suggests? I need to do it this way because I have objects binded to the `newState` variable's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set newState equal to `{new:'new'}` with this line:
`var newState = state.set_primary({"new":"new"});`

Note that newState does not hold any reference to `state` or to `state.current_form`

So when you run this line:
`schedule(state);`
It changes state.current_form.primary, but it has no effect on the `{ new: 'new' }` object that was assigned to newState.

If you WANT to see a change you can do this:

```
var state = new formState();
var newState = state.current_form;
state.set_primary({"new":"new"});
console.log("newState = ", newState.primary);
schedule(state);
console.log("newState = ", newState.primary);
```

this will print:

```
newState =  { new: 'new' }
newState =  { updated: 'updated' }
```

Note the difference. In this version of the code, newState is set to the current_form object which is not replaced by the call to set_primary. Now, when `state.current_form.primary` is set to reference the object `{updated:'updated'}`, `newState.primary` points to the updated object.

Answer (score 0):

At first, `this.current_form.primary` refers the object `{"new":"new"}` and that is returned to be assigned in `newState`. At this point both `newState` and `this.current_form.primary` refer the same object. You can confirm that like this

```
console.log(newState === state.current_form.primary);
```

But, the next time, when you call `schedule`, it assigns a new object to `current_form.primary`. So, `current_form.primary` and `newState` point to different objects now. That is why `newState` still shows `{new: "new"}`.